# Cone condition for Wave equation with Singular Speed

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

Consider a wave equation of the form
$$
    \partial_t^2u(t,x)-c(t)^2\partial_x^2u(t,x)=0, \quad (t,x)\in (0,1]\times \mathbb{R}
$$
where the speed $c(t)$ is in $L^1([0,1]) \cap C^1((0,1])$. This would mean that the speed may entertain logarithmic singularity.

The Cauchy problem for the above wave operator is well-posed in $C^\infty$. The well-posedness is established via an energy estimate by Colombini et. al (Colombini, F.; Del Santo, D.; Kinoshita, T.: Well-posedness of the Cauchy problem for a hyperbolic equation with non-Lipschitz coefficients. Ann. Scoula Norm Sup. Pisa Cl. Sci. 1(2002) 327-358).

Will the operator satisfy the cone condition? Especially, what will be the domain of influence when initial conditions are given at $t=0$?

Can anyone suggest some reference for determining cone condition for wave equation with singular speed?

Comment: In the paper to which you refer, the well-posedness is proved via Fourier transform: you deal with the family of ODE, $\partial_t^2 v+c(t)^2\xi^2 v=f$. I guess that following the same route and the energy estimates, you will be able to prove finite speed of propagation, but you need to look up into the article.

Comment: I am interested in knowing what will be the optimal slope of the cone. Energy estimate just tells me that speed of propagation is finite.